# How to get only the data by current date from API in react-native?

Tags: react-native, api

Can someone show an example function how can I get data from API only for current date ?

Comment: If your API supports a data parameter you can simply pass it, or you will have to get all data and filter by date in client side, can you share the code on where you want to filter ?